# AJAX for successful php :: delete checked table list :: using hyperlink NOT input

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, delete-row, sql-delete

**Project Focus:** Delete Multi-checked table list from form.
**Specs:** 
1.) Delete actioned by using `<a href>` hyperlink (NOT `<input type="submit"`
2.) I'd like to action this with AJAX, including ***confirm*** & ***error/success*** **responses**.
**Status of Delete Action:** I've finally got my code working to delete multi-checkboxes. *See the successful PHP Code Snippet below.*
**Note:** the successful $_POST coding is currently being handled in the same page by using `<input type="submit" name="delete>"`.

I've tried to get it to work, but no luck. Could someone please have a look through the coding & script to see if you can spot any errors?

**My thoughts (but uncertain):**
1) the ajax `var formData` is written wrong to achieve getting both `$delete = $_POST['delete'];` and `$chkbx = $_POST['chkbx'];`
2) Instead of `.click` for `<a href"#" id="#btn_del"` should maybe try for using `.post`

### Form

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" name="recordsForm" id="recordsForm">
```

### Button

**UPDATED (for spec#1)** updated the `href` to `href="deleteRecord.php"`

```
<li class="button" id="toolbar-del">
    <a href="#" title="Delete" id="btn_del">
        <span class="icon-16-delete dead"></span>
        Delete
    </a>
</li>
```

### PHP Code Snippet:

This code is currently included at the bottom of the form. Later, I would like to move it as a function to a separate actions.php page that will include additional button actions (edit, duplicate, archive, etc). For now, I'll be happy to just move it to **deleteRecord.php** page & call it with this AJAX.

```
<?
                                // Check if DELETE button active, start this
$delete         = $_POST['delete'];
$chkbx          = $_POST['chkbx'];

if($delete){
 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
   $del_id  = $chkbx[$i];
   $sql     = "DELETE FROM ".ID_TABLE." WHERE unit_id='".$del_id."'";
   $result  = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
 }
                                // if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php
 if($result){
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=records_manager.php\">";
    }else{
        echo "Error: No luck";
    }
  }
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

### ajaxDELETE

```
// ajaxDelete.js
$(document).ready(function() {
                                                    // When TRASH button is clicked...
$('#btn_del').click(function(event) {

    e.preventDefault();                             // stop the form submitting the normal way
                                                    // and refreshing the page  

    // Get the form data                            // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery
    // ----------------------------------           // (you can use the class or id also)
    var formData = {
              'chkbx'   : $('input[name=chkbx]').val(),
              'count'   : $count[0]

    // Process the form
    // ================
    $.ajax({
              type      : 'POST',                   // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use
              url       : 'deleteRecord.php',       // the url where we want to POST
              data      : formData,                 // our data object
              dataType  : 'json',                   // what type of data do we expect back from the server
              encode    : true
          })

                                                    // using the .done(), 
                                                    // promise callback
    .done(function(data) {                      

        window.console.log(data);                   // log data to the console so we can see

        // Handle ERRORS
        if ( ! data.success) {                                      

            if (data.errors.chkbx) {                
                $('.Records_Found').addClass('has-error');
                $('.Records_Found').append('<div class="help-block">'+ data.errors.chkbx + '</div>');   
            }
        }                                           // end if ERRORS
        else {
            $('.Records_Found').append('<div class="alert alert-success" id="valid_success">'+ data.message + '</div>');
    // After form submission,
                                                    // redirect a user to another page
        window.location = 'records_manager.php'; 
              }
          })

          .fail(function(data) {                    // promise callback
          window.console.log(data);  });            // show any errors in console
                                                    // NOTE: it's best to remove for production

          event.preventDefault();                   // stop the form from submitting the normal way
                                                    // and refreshing the page  
      });                                           // end submit button

    });                                             // end document ready
```

### deleteRecord.php

```
<?php

// FUNCTION to DELETE
// ===========================
// :checked existing unit data

$errors = array();                      // array to hold validation errors
$data   = array();                      // array to pass back data

if ( empty($_POST['chkbx']))                // if empty, populate error
    $errors['chkbx'] = 'No items have been checked yet.';
// ERROR! Return a response
if ( ! empty($errors)) {        

    $data['success'] = false;           // any errors = return a success boolean of FALSE
    $data['errors']  = $errors;         // return those errors

} else {                            

// NO ERROR... Carry on                     // Process the form data  
    require_once('config.php');             // Connect to the database

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        or die ('Error connecting to MySQL server.'.$dbc);
                                            // Check if DELETE 
$delete         = $_POST['delete'];
$chkbx          = $_POST['chkbx'];
$count          = $_POST['count'];

if($delete){
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $del_id     = $chkbx[$i];
        $sql        = "DELETE FROM ".ID_TABLE." WHERE unit_id='".$del_id."'";
        $result     = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
    }
                                            // if successful redirect
    if($result){
            echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=records_manager.php\">";
    }else{
            echo "Error: No luck";
    }
}
mysqli_close($dbc);                             // close DB connection
}
$data['success'] = true;                        // show a message of success 
$data['message'] = 'Success!';                  // and provide a true success variable
}
echo json_encode($data);                        // return all our data to an AJAX call  
}                                               // end else NO ERRORS, process form 
?>
```

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: First error is telling me the `var count` is written wrong in ajax

Comment: is `$count` a variable you declared in your php script?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes `$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);` successfully produces an accurate count.

Comment: And you will be hack in 3 min, never use this kind of logic in your code `$chkbx = $_POST['chkbx'];  $del_id     = $chkbx[$i]; WHERE unit_id='".$del_id."'";` search sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Digging through loads of bookmarks, I'd found an example of what I was hoping to achieve. After fiddling with snippets of codes, I've finally gotten the ajax to work as I'd hoped to achieve for this step of the project.
To hopefully assist others in their search for this, below, I've provided all coding for both ajax/jq/js & php that worked flawlessly in my tests.

### How this code works

- The button (a hyperlink `outside of the form`, `NOT an input button`) is linked to the `deletedRecord.php`, but the script overrides the link with `e.preventDefault()`
- JQ is used to build the array of ***checked row IDs*** & send them to `deletedRecord.php` via AJAX
- `deleteRecord.php` **explodes** the array, **counts** the total number of checked IDs, and finally loops through the query to delete each.
- Upon successful completion, a response of `1` is echo'd back to trigger the success action

Hope this helps someone out there. If anyone sees any other faults I might've missed, please feel free to share for the greater good. Cheers.

### ajaxDelete.js

**Notes:**
 
1.) Updated the image (button) `href` to `href="deleteRecord.php"`
2.) Researched & found a better [approach](http://sharemyphp.wordpress.com/2009/12/21/ajax-jquery-php-multiple-delete-item-with-check-box/) that reduced the count to only the checked (I thought this would be more effective (faster) in case the table grew to a large number of rows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btn_del').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 
    page    = $(this).attr("href");
    ids     = new Array()
    a       = 0;

    $(".chk:checked").each(function(){
       ids[a] = $(this).val();
       a++;
})   
      // alert(ids);

if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete these courses?")) {

     $.ajax({
            url         :   page,
            type        :   "POST",
            data        :   "id="+ids,
            dataType    :   'json',
            success     :   function(res) {
                             if ( res == 1 ) {
                                 $(".chk:checked").each(function() {
                                     $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                                  })        // end if then remove table row
                                }           // end if res ==1
                             }              // end success response function
            })                              // end ajax
     }                                      // end confirmed
return false;
});                                         // end button click function
});                                         // end doc ready
```

### deleteRecord.php

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');                 // Connect to the database

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        or die ('Error connecting to MySQL server.'.$dbc);

    $del_id = explode(",",$_POST['id']);
    $count = count($del_id);
        if (count($count) > 0) {
            foreach ($del_id as $id) {
                      $sql = "DELETE FROM ".ID_TABLE."
                              WHERE unit_id='" . $id . "'";
                      $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql) 
                              or die(mysqli_error($dbc)); 
            }                                   // end for each as

        mysqli_close($dbc);                     // close MySQL

        echo json_encode(1);                    // Return json res == 1
                                                // this is used for the SUCCESS action
        }                                       // end if count > 0
?>
```